# Не Работает delete and edit

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('6660930091:AAHK6-Xywpp_msVwUdV-ibw-mOWxQtOFxrc')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def media_logger(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Open My Github', url='https://github.com/ArtyomHovhannisyan09')
    markup.row(btn1)
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Delete', callback_data='delete')
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Edit Text', callback_data='edit')
    markup.row(btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Please do not send photos, videos, and audio because I cannot work with such files.', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == 'delete':
        bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
    elif callback.data == 'edit':
        bot.edit_message_text('Edited text', callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») 
должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и 
*минимальный* код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного 
описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать 
минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 1) Наверно плохая идея выкладывать токен на публику. 2) Как понять "не работает"? Что конкретно не работает? Что вы ожидали увидеть, и что увидели по факту. Ошибка, не ошибка? Хоть что-то.

Answer (score 0):

Я просто неправильно сделал когда я работал в Telegram Web  там это всё не работает но когда я скачал телеграмм desktop или использовал телефон все работает